# What image can I use to experiment with Comet and WAListenerAdaptor in Seaside?

Tags: pharo, seaside

How can I give [this example](http://book.seaside.st/book/web-20/comet/getting-started) a go. I can't seem to find an image to experiment with, that still includes WAListenerAdaptor .

Any links?

Answer (score 0):

The new equivalent in Pharo is `ZnZincServerAdaptor startOn: XXXX`.